# Open two controller A & B on one tab item in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem, I want to open two view Controllers on single tab from to different way. 
Like:
Login Screen --> Home Screen --> On home screen two button A & B

1 When click on the button A, open A controller on tab controller tab1

2 When click on the button B, open B controller on tab controller tab1

I have 5 tab in tab controller.

Please help me for that issue.
Please refer attached screen for more help.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: In your home screen 5 buttons are there right ??By clicking it navigate to another tab bar controller with particular tab selection right?

Comment: add childviewcontrollers to your A controller and then on click of button show and hide

Comment: I have update my question. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can replace ViewController By using this

```
 func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {


        let selectIndex : NSInteger = (tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController))!

        if (selectIndex == 1) {


                let vc = UIViewController()  // your new Controller

                var allviews = tabBarController.viewControllers
                 allviews?.remove(at: selectIndex)
                 allviews?.insert(vc, at: selectIndex)
            tabBarController.setViewControllers(allviews, animated: true)


                return false;

        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help I will try and let you know.

Comment: tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3    used to make tabbar D selected

Comment: Yes, I have done already but can you please refer updated question with screen shot.
I want to open D tab item when click on A and B Button and from A buttom open A view Controller and from B button open B view controller on single tab D.
This is my question.
Thanks

Comment: you need to have backaction on selected tabbarController  or what ?

Comment: Yes on back action I closed the entire tabController and back to Home screen on which A & B button are showing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out this easy solution to manipulate viewcontrollers by modifiying the array and reattach it to the tabbarcontroller. I used it for loading a *LoginViewController in LoggedOut state* - removing my default *UserPreferenceViewcontroller.*

Answer (score 0):

(Please add some more information to your question, or at least code to know what have you tried.)

By your question, It seems you need a `Tab Bar Controller`.

You use tab bar controller to organize your app into one or more distinct modes of operation. The view hierarchy of a tab bar controller is self contained. It is composed of views that the tab bar controller manages directly and views that are managed by content view controllers you provide. Each content view controller manages a distinct view hierarchy, and the tab bar controller coordinates the navigation between the view hierarchies.

[image]